# PyQT dynamically, automatically changing color properties of table widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Since I am new in PyQt I am trying to solve a problem with dynamically change color of table cell - help is more than welcome.

Function *testFunction* should change tableWidget color if *for loop* find 1 in array or 0. Is it possible to set this properties? Box should automatically change color on every 2 seconds without any additional action. Check the code below...

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello!")
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.tableItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.resize(400,250)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("START TOOL"))
        self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,150))

        realLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        realLayout.addWidget(tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(realLayout)
        self.testFunction()

    def testFunction(self) :
        a = [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        for i in range(0,len(a)) :
            if a[i] == 1 :
                self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,100))
            else :
                self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0))    
            time.sleep(2)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Comment: Your code is not working since you need to first add data to your tableWidget. Currently, you tableWidget is empty. Here is a simple [example](https://pythonspot.com/en/qt4-table/) on how to add data. Also you need to have a single reference to `tableWidget`, for this use `self.tableWidget` instead.

Comment: Thanks @SyedElec. I have modify the code according to your suggestions. Now I still need to automatically assign and change color to table cell. The main idea is that changing the items in array "a" should cause changing of background color in real time.

Comment: @IvanB how do change array "a"?

Comment: @eyllanesc array "a" will be changed dynamically by appending some new values of zeros and ones (it is not a matter of this code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change `realLayout.addWidget(tableWidget)` to `realLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)` and and you should not use "sleep", must create a timer(`QTimer`)

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello!")
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.tableItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.resize(400, 250)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("START TOOL"))
        self.tableWidget.item(0, 0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 150))

        realLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        realLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(realLayout)
        self.counter = 0
        self.a = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        self.testFunction()

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.testFunction)
        timer.start(2*1000)

    def testFunction(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.counter %= len(self.a)
        if self.a[self.counter]:
            self.tableWidget.item(0, 0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 100))
        else:
            self.tableWidget.item(0, 0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @SyedElec It still won't work. When program reach the timer testFunction performs whole iteration process in for loop instead of step by step. Step by step will feed table cell with blinking effect, so I expected that after timer is reached testFunction perform only a[0] iteration and change the color of table cell, after 2 seconds, only a[1] after a[2] and so on, and change color for every state...

Comment: @IvanB see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235